# In my custom UIButton class, why is my highlight layer not vanishing?

Tags: objective-c

I've created a custom subclass of UIButton to encapsulate some specific issues I have (client wants to have a gradient as the background for most of his buttons).  So far, this effort has worked as planned.

However, one of the things I created was a custom 'highlight' to replace the built-in highlight, since custom buttons aren't allowed that.  I've had great luck with overriding the superclass function for highlighting as follows:

```
-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    NSLog(@"Set highlighted called: %i", highlighted);
    if (self.highlight==nil) {
        self.highlight=[CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.colors=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:.4] CGColor], 
                         (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:.4] CGColor],
                         nil];
    }
    if(highlighted)
    {
        [[self layer] addSublayer:highlight];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Highlight should be removed...");
        NSLog(@"Highlight index: %i", [[[self layer] sublayers] indexOfObject:highlight]);
        [self.highlight removeFromSuperlayer];
        NSLog(@"Highlight index: %i", [[[self layer] sublayers] indexOfObject:highlight]);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the highlight layer doesn't seem to remove itself properly.  As you can see in my code, I'm checking to see what index the highlight is at before removal (2) and after removal (2147483647, AKA NSNotFound).  So it is, in theory, removed from the layer.

But for some reason, it's still being *displayed* inside the custom button, and I don't know why.

For now I"m going to work around by simply changing the background gradient's colors on highlight, but I'm really curious as to why this code isn't working.

Comment: Do you need to ask the button to redraw? `setNeedsDisplay`

Comment: Tried that at one point, no go.